# Is it better to have acrylic window inserts than storm windows for soundproofing?

Tags: windows, sound-proofing

We live on a busy street and would like to soundproof the windows facing the street. After some research, we've boiled down to either storm windows or acrylic glass. The latter is more expensive, but will the storm windows be enough to block the noise? If so, which storm windows would you recommend (what we found mostly have aluminum frames)?

Comment: As Ed Beal says, acrylic is fairly soft. It'll be swirled and cloudy before too long. Do you have some reason to think that acrylic will dampen sound more effectively?

Answer (score 1):

Although this may be some what an opinion based question shopping questions are off topic. Storm windows create a extra air chamber and do a good job of dampening outside sound if properly installed.
I don’t know if I would want acrylic windows unless sandwiched with glass because acrylic scratches so easily but you may be talking about a window technology I am unaware of.